# Displaying small values using highcharts.js

Tags: highcharts

I'm plotting a bar chart which has some large values and some smaller ones, the way in which the y-axis scales makes my smaller values not appear on the chart (no bar is displayed for the smaller values), but you can see the value when you mouse over.

This makes it really hard to differentiate between data points with value 0 and data points with very small values, is there a way that I can make the small value data points show up as bars on the chart?

Comment: Also, here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arjunbadarinath/V6fvX/

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing a different scale of the yAxis or using the `'logarithmic'` type. See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/V6fvX/1/).
Note that this does not work in all cases. The HighCharts user voice site has been asking for scale-break capabilities for a while now.

**EDIT**

A log scale cannot have a value of 0. So, you will either have to deal with not showing this point in a tooltip or hoping you dont get it as a value. I have tried to do some overrides of the tooltip function to read from the series.data values but that did not work out and my javascript is not so much good. Basically we are stuck with either points that do not show do to huge range differences or points that show excpet when 0 when using log scale. I go with the latter.

Comment: This approach works well, but for a data point of 0, the mouse over shows the wrong value (in the mouse for a 0 data point over I see the previous data point's value).

Comment: That is interesting...you are not seeing the previous points value - you are just not seeing the tooltip for the 0-point. Looks like a bug to me in that it should handle LOG 0 (which is undefined)! See https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/724194-add-logarithmic-axes

Comment: For the 0 point values why not just use null as the value...or keep that item and modify the tooltip. See updated answer above.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set `minPointLength` for series: http://jsfiddle.net/V6fvX/2/

Comment: With this approach all the small values end up with bars of the same height, even if you have a data point of value 0 that shows up as a bar with height 10, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This is only approach. You can set null instead of 0 to make sure that  bars won't be displayed at all.

Answer (score -1):

It works!

Set minPointLength, then the zero values into null.

jsfiddle.net/nxehwL7r/2/

Comment: You are showing a jsfiddle in which you didn't apply both things you just said.